# Annotations with images in the background

Tags: qgis, annotation

I was wondering if it is possible to insert text into a QGIS map not just in composer, similar to the Insert Text in ArcMap? I'm trying to put in custom labels with an image as the text box. I've tried the text annotation function but I can't make that work. Is there any other options?

I need to place a text box on a map and it has to be visible there and in composer so I don't have to add the text box to every new composer created.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new vector layer (point or line), with an attribute for the label text. 
Then, you can simply hide its symbology (no outline and transparent fill) and activate the labels, styling them as you like.

For the final map in the print composer, be sure to exclude it from the legend.